# How to fire mongodb inside react and node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have cloned react, express and mongodb app.

on the root folder of the project after doing `npm install` I did `npm start`. App says `Server started at port: 5000`. The guy says run mongodb.

I did `mongod` and `mongo` but the app is empty. There's no data in app. How do I find data base within the app and link it to mongodb?

Comment: Where are you *expecting* the data to come from?

Comment: Have you downloaded mongodb on your computer? It seems you are just starting to build full stack application so I suggest you use something called mongo atlas.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not sure. I am trying to find where the data are stored but could not find. The original user says `run npm start` and run mongo to see all the data inside the app.confused!!

Comment: @HenryLy yes I have mongodb community version. when I do mongod --dbpath=(what path should I include)?

I include the path of a folder that I just created within root of my computer. Do I need to include the path that has data for that database?

Answer (score 0):

Learning to build restful api can be confusing in the beginning so I will try to break the code you are going to see . Also I would recommend watching this guys video that give a basic teaching of building restful api of the technology that you just mention => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjf774RKrLc

> 1. start server by specifying which port to listening too

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express()

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log('server is starting')
}
```

> 2. npm i mongoose and connect to a database. So this can go two way. #Option 1 : You can either download mongodb => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmP_X4UuGos and connect it like the example below or #Option 2 : You can use mongoAtlas to quickly connect to a database in the cloud (recommended if you are a beginner) => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuCrHynro0w.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

//Option 1 

mongoose.connection("mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject", () =>{
   console.log("database is connected")
)

//Option 2 => Just follow along the first video I sent you and 
//that should give you a good understanding on how to build restful api 

mongoose.connection("MONGO-URL-PROVIDED-BY-MONGOATLAS", () =>{
   console.log("database is connected")
)




app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log('server is starting')
}
```

Comment: I also notice that you are working with a MERN (mongo, express, react, node) stack so watch this video to build full stack application => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CqJlxBYj-M